# Why won't Colab import fpgrowth from mlxtend.frequent_patterns?

Tags: google-colaboratory, mlxtend

When I import `mlxtend.frequent_patterns`, the function `fpgrowth` and `fpmax` are not  there. However, they are there if I use Jupyter Notebook in Anaconda Navigator.

Anyone know why Colab will not import?

```
import pandas as pd

from mlxtend.preprocessing import TransactionEncoder
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori, fpmax, fpgrowth
```

> ImportError
> Traceback (most recent call last)
>
>  in ()
> 2 
> 3 from mlxtend.preprocessing import TransactionEncoder
> ----> 4 from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori, fpmax, fpgrowth
> 5 
> 6 
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'fpmax' from 'mlxtend.frequent_patterns' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mlxtend/frequent_patterns/**init**.py)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue just now. The first solution suggested was to pip the package using this in a code cell:

```
! pip install mlxtend
```

However, while that helped with me using `apriori`, it did not help with `fpgrowth`. Then, after about three hours, I found a solution. Again, in a code cell, run this:

```
%pip install mlxtend --upgrade
```

I'm not sure what the `%` does that the `!` does not.

Comment: Well it's the `--upgrade` that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Colab by default installs some older version of the library.

Try with this specific version.
Run the following command:
`!pip install mlxtend==0.17.0`